# Is it grammatically correct to ask "How is going everything?"

Tags: word-order, greetings

Is it grammatically correct to say:

> How is going everything?

And does it convey same meaning as "How is going your life?"

Comment: For future reference, consider [waiting longer](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/not-so-fast-when-should-i-accept-my-answer) before accepting an answer. You might get more or better answers this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Cambridge Dictionary

> [Questions: wh-questions](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/questions-wh-questions)
>   Wh-questions begin with what, when, where, who, whom, which, whose, why and how.
>   Forming wh-questions
>   With an auxiliary verb
>
> We usually form wh-questions with wh- + an auxiliary verb (be, do or have) + subject + main verb or with wh- + a modal verb + subject + main verb

Here, the *wh-* is *how*, the auxiliary verb is *is*, the subject is *everything*, and the main verb is *going*. So it should be

> 1. How is everything going?

This is a common question asking about someone's life and I assume it means the same as "How is going your life?" (like OP said). "How is going your life?" is incorrect. Again, it would be

> 2. How is your life going?

2 asks the same as 1, although 2 might be less common than 1 and possibly rude.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite. Switch to "**How is everything going?**". It's a common idiom that does have the meaning of "How is your life going", and it's often used as a greeting.